# Performance Improvement Basics in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, big-o

So this is an algorithms question I was working out on HackerRank. It passes all the test cases except one because it **times out.**

I tried making a couple of improvements but it still keeps timing out. I want to understand how you can look at your own code and find places where it is slow.

Please note that I am not looking at alternative logics to solve the problem. This is the solution that came to my mind and I want to try and quicken it.

The question is as follows:

**Problem Statement**

Given a list of N integers, your task is to select K integers from the list such that its unfairness is minimized.

If (x1,x2,x3,…,xk) are K numbers selected from the list N, the unfairness is defined as

max(x1,x2,…,xk)−min(x1,x2,…,xk)
where max denotes the largest integer among the elements of K, and min denotes the smallest integer among the elements of K.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer N. 
The second line contains an integer K. 
N lines follow. Each line contains an integer that belongs to the list N.

Link to the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/angry-children/copy-from/11910253

**First attempt:**

```
n, k = int(input()), int(input())
num = sorted([ int(input()) for i in range(0,n) ])
lower, min_unfairness, upper = 0, 0, k

while upper <= len(num):
    current    = num[lower:upper]
    unfairness = current[-1] - current[0]
    if lower == 0: 
        min_unfairness = unfairness
    else: 
        if unfairness < min_unfairness:
            min_unfairness = unfairness 

    if min_unfairness == 0:
        break

    lower += 1
    upper += 1

print (min_unfairness)
```

**Second Attempt:** Improved further by removing the check for lower == 0 from the loop since that happens only in the first iteration.

```
n, k = int(input()), int(input())
num = sorted([ int(input()) for i in range(0,n) ])
lower, min_unfairness, upper = 0, 0, k

#Finding the unfairness of the 1st set and assigning it as min
current    = num[lower:upper]
unfairness = current[-1] - current[0]
min_unfairness = unfairness
lower += 1
upper += 1

while upper <= len(num) and min_unfairness != 0:

    #Finding unfairness of current set
    current    = num[lower:upper]
    unfairness = current[-1] - current[0]

    #Set it as min if it is lower than current minimum
    if unfairness < min_unfairness:
        min_unfairness = unfairness 

    lower += 1
    upper += 1

print (min_unfairness)
```

I am not sure what approach I should take whilte trying to analyse this problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Start with [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: Would it bother you if I gave you a one-liner to replace all but your first two lines?

Comment: Not at all. Go ahead. Suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: Nevermind.  Just realized my idea was about the same as Kolmar's.

Comment: Okay. This is brilliant :D

Comment: How do you actually come up with such a solution? What is your thought process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Kolmar and Steven's help, I wrote the following piece:

```
n, k = int(input()), int(input())
num = sorted([ int(input()) for i in range(0,n) ])
min_unfairness = min( max_value - min_value for min_value, max_value in    zip(num, num[k-1:]) )
print(min_unfairness)
```

Posting it as an answer here, so that if anyone wants to have a quick look at the answer, they can see this :)

Answer (score 2):

The slowest thing you do is copying a part of the list: `current = num[lower:upper]`. This brings the complexity of this step up from O(n) to O(n•k).

What you really should do is just take the elements, which define the unfairness of this sublist directly by their indexes:

```
min_unfairness = min(num[i+k-1] - num[i] for i in range(n-k+1))
```

**Clarification**: When the index of the first element of some selection is `i`, the largest element has index `i+k-1`, so the unfairness of this selection is equal to `num[i+k-1] - num[i]`. The code `(num[i+k-1] - num[i] for i in range(n-k+1))` gives the iterator over unfairnesses of the relevant selections. So `min(num[i+k-1] - num[i] for i in range(n-k+1))` finds the smallest unfairness in this iterator.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but are you sure the expression you have posted matches what is needed?

Comment: @GauravKeswani I've submitted your code, with the whole `while` loop replaced with my expression and it has passed all the tests. Try it yourself.

Comment: Oh okay. I haven't understood it completely yet to be honest. Let me try and come up with something similar myself.

Comment: Just a thought. The min_unfairness can never be less than 0. Imagine a situation with a billion pairs where the first pair returns the unfairness of 0. Wouldn't your code to a lot of unnecessary processing in that case?

Comment: I am just trying to give you my thought process here. Not trying to challenge your answer knowing that it passed all the test cases :)

Comment: @GauravKeswani No, your questions are OK. I've also added some clarification. Yes it would, and yes, it's possible to improve this and return early, when we find an unfairness of 0. The thing is, it's not the important thing for this problem. Largest N is 100 000. So even my code will check at most 100 000 indexes. But if you copy the sublist, the complexity becomes O(n*k), and that's up to 50 000 * 50 000 -- that's too much to pass the tests. (Also, sorting the sequence is O(n log n), which takes considerably more time than checking N indexes, so even my code is effective enough)

Comment: @Guarav Keswani:  In real-world code you might want to short-cut processing to keep the average run-time down.  But really all you need to care about here is max run-time.  And, as Kolmar points out, your Big O complexity is what's killing you.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Found it easier to understand your solution with the zip(). Still trying to grasp Kolmar's solution :)

Comment: @Kolmar This line of code will also work only if the list is sorted right?

Comment: @GauravKeswani Yes, the same as your code. Also, nice solution, it's definitely more readable than mine. (They do pretty much the same thing: yours finds the largest element of selection with `zip`, and mine with index fiddling).

Comment: @Kolmar The solution is Steven's